# Converting LTR to RTL?

Tags: c++, regex, delphi, uniscribe

As you know many ui components and dev tools doesn't support rtl , we can call it **flipping text** , cause result is same example :

**LTR**

```
سلام salam متن راهنما word
```

**RTL**

```
word متن راهنما salam  سلام
```

is there anyway to convert this LTR to RTL , i don't have any idea and language doesn't matter

Actually i am seeking for a solution to get this done in RAD Studio Firemonkey Application , as you may know firemonkey apps doesn't support rtl it's in roadmap of rad studio but not implemented yet

Comment: I don't think it would be easy for you to graft a fix onto FMX to make this work. Perhaps it could be done for text out but it's going to be a challenge to make editing work I imagine. You may need to wait until FMX is done.

Comment: The relevant Mac OS X API is "ATSUI" or Apple Type Services for Unicode Imaging, and the Win32 API is UNISCRIBE.  Until FMX provides a library with a common API that wraps both, good luck.  I'm sure that QT already has it, so whoever is implementing this could study how they did it in QT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Windows, you can do that via the [UniScribe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374091%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

I've used this to convert Unicode text into set of glyphs, for our [Open Source PDF writer](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/05/06/Synopse-PDF-engine-1.7.2).

You have source code sample in [SynPdf.pas](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynPdf.pas) unit. See the `TPdfWrite.AddUnicodeHexTextUniScribe` method:

```
function TPdfWrite.AddUnicodeHexTextUniScribe(PW: PWideChar;
  WinAnsiTTF: TPdfFontTrueType; NextLine: boolean; Canvas: TPdfCanvas): boolean;
var L, i,j: integer;
    res: HRESULT;
    max, count, numSp: integer;
    Sp: PScriptPropertiesArray;
    W: PWideChar;
    items: array of TScriptItem;
    level: array of byte;
    VisualToLogical: array of integer;
    psc: pointer; // opaque Uniscribe font metric cache
    complex,R2L: boolean;
    complexs: array of byte;
    glyphs: array of TScriptVisAttr;
    glyphsCount: integer;
    OutGlyphs, LogClust: array of word;
procedure Append(i: Integer);
// local procedure used to add glyphs from items[i] to the PDF content stream
var L: integer;
    W: PWideChar;
procedure DefaultAppend;
var tmpU: array of WideChar;
begin
  SetLength(tmpU,L+1); // we need the text to be ending with #0
  move(W^,tmpU[0],L*2);
  AddUnicodeHexTextNoUniScribe(pointer(tmpU),WinAnsiTTF,false,Canvas);
end;
begin
  L := items[i+1].iCharPos-items[i].iCharPos; // length of this shapeable item
  if L=0 then
    exit; // nothing to append
  W := PW+items[i].iCharPos;
  if not GetBit(complexs[0],i) then begin
    // not complex items are rendered as fast as possible
    DefaultAppend;
    exit;
  end;
  res := ScriptShape(0,psc,W,L,max,@items[i].a,
    pointer(OutGlyphs),pointer(LogClust),pointer(glyphs),glyphsCount);
  case res of
    E_OUTOFMEMORY: begin // max was not big enough (should never happen)
      DefaultAppend;
      exit;
    end;
    E_PENDING, USP_E_SCRIPT_NOT_IN_FONT: begin // need HDC and a selected font object
      res := ScriptShape(Canvas.FDoc.GetDCWithFont(WinAnsiTTF),
        psc,W,L,max,@items[i].a,
        pointer(OutGlyphs),pointer(LogClust),pointer(glyphs),glyphsCount);
      if res<>0 then begin // we won't change font if necessary, sorry
        // we shall implement the complex technic as stated by
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374105(v=VS.85).aspx
        DefaultAppend;
        exit;
      end;
    end;
    0: ; // success -> will add glyphs just below
    else exit;
  end;
  // add glyphs to the PDF content
  // (NextLine has already been handled: not needed here)
  AddGlyphs(pointer(OutGlyphs),glyphsCount,Canvas);
end;
begin
  result := false; // on UniScribe error, handle as Unicode
  // 1. Breaks a Unicode string into individually shapeable items
  L := StrLenW(PW)+1; // include last #0
  max := L+2; // should be big enough
  SetLength(items,max);
  count := 0;
  if ScriptItemize(PW,L,max,nil,nil,pointer(items),count)<>0 then
    exit; // error trying processing Glyph Shaping -> fast return
  // 2. guess if requiring glyph shaping or layout
  SetLength(complexs,(count shr 3)+1);
  ScriptGetProperties(sP,numSp);
  complex := false;
  R2L := false;
  for i := 0 to Count-2 do // don't need Count-1 = Terminator
    if fComplex in sP^[items[i].a.eScript and (1 shl 10-1)]^.fFlags then begin
      complex := true;
      SetBit(complexs[0],i);
    end else
      if fRTL in items[i].a.fFlags then
        R2L := true;
  if not complex then begin
    // no glyph shaping -> fast append as normal Unicode Text
    if R2L then begin
      // handle Right To Left but not Complex text
      W := pointer(items); // there is enough temp space in items[]
      W[L] := #0;
      dec(L);
      for i := 0 to L do
        W[i] := PW[L-i];
      AddUnicodeHexTextNoUniScribe(W,WinAnsiTTF,NextLine,Canvas);
      result := true; // mark handled here
    end;
    exit;
  end;
  // 3. get Visual Order, i.e. how to render the content from left to right
  SetLength(level,count);
  for i := 0 to Count-1 do
    level[i] := items[i].a.s.uBidiLevel;
  SetLength(VisualToLogical,count);
  if ScriptLayout(Count,pointer(level),pointer(VisualToLogical),nil)<>0 then
    exit;
  // 4. now we have enough information to start drawing
  result := true;
  if NextLine then
    Canvas.MoveToNextLine; // manual NextLine handling
  // 5. add glyphs for all shapeable items
  max := (L*3)shr 1+32; // should be big enough - allocate only once
  SetLength(glyphs,max);
  SetLength(OutGlyphs,max);
  SetLength(LogClust,max);
  psc := nil; // cached for the same character style used
  if Canvas.RightToLeftText then
    // append from right to left visual order
    for j := Count-2 downto 0 do // Count-2: ignore last ending item
      Append(VisualToLogical[j]) else
    // append from left to right visual order
    for j := 0 to Count-2 do // Count-2: ignore last ending item
      Append(VisualToLogical[j]);
end;
```

Of course, this is under Windows only. So it won't work on Mac OS X. You'll have to use another library under Mac OS X...

Answer (score 1):

It's complicated. If you want to do it correctly, you must use the [Bidi Library](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ubidi_8h.html) from the [International Components for Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: Do you have something like an example?

Comment: So FMX could wrap ICU for example.  That might even be the FMX team's plan.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [MFC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-desktop-applications?view=vs-2019), here is how to set both righting direction and alignment. Assuming your CEdit control is named **m_TextEdit**:

```
void MyDialog::SetLangDirection(bool RTL)
{
    DWORD w_dwStyle;

    w_dwStyle = GetWindowLong(m_TextEdit.GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_EXSTYLE);

    if (RTL)
    {
        w_dwStyle -= WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING;
        w_dwStyle |= WS_EX_RIGHT | WS_EX_RTLREADING;
    }
    else
    {
        w_dwStyle -= WS_EX_RIGHT | WS_EX_RTLREADING;
        w_dwStyle |= WS_EX_LEFT | WS_EX_LTRREADING;
    }

    SetWindowLong(m_TextEdit.GetSafeHwnd(), GWL_EXSTYLE, w_dwStyle);
}
```

See [my tip](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5272828/Setting-Write-Direction-and-Alignment).